# How can I convert Iterable <com.datastax.driver.core.Row> to Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I use Spark 2.0 and Scala 2.11.8.

I have a Cassandra ResultSet from a select query and I want to convert it to a Spark DataFrame or Dataset. How?

I've been trying to use this connector:

```
"com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0-RC1"
```

and also later this:

```
"com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0-M3"
```

The code:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().
  setAppName(appName).
  set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.60.50.134").
  set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "xyz").
  set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "abc")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
val rdd = spark.
  sparkContext.
  cassandraTable(keyspace = s"$keyspace", table = s"$table")
rdd.take(10).foreach(println)
```

With both I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.KeyspaceMetadata.getMaterializedViews()Ljava/util/Collection;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1(Schema.scala:281)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:305)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:304)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:683)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:316)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:682)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1(Schema.scala:304)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:325)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:322)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:122)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:322)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.tableFromCassandra(Schema.scala:342)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:137)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1292)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.take(CassandraRDD.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.take(CassandraRDD.scala:122)
```

Comment: The latest version of the connector is `2.0.1-s_2.11`. Can you try it? Can you also use `spark.read.format` to read from Cassandra since that's the recommended approach (both in Spark Cassandra Connector and Spark 2.1 itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a pre-Dataset API of Spark Cassandra Connector as it supports Datasets out of the box (but may require different way of loading data from Cassandra tables).

My recommendation is to re-write/upgrade your code to use Spark Cassandra Connector's [Dataset-friendly API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#datasets-previously-dataframes).

From [Example Changing Cluster/Keyspace Level Properties](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#example-changing-clusterkeyspace-level-properties):

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "words", "keyspace" -> "test"))
  .load() // This Dataset will use a spark.cassandra.input.size of 128
```

And later in [Creating Datasets using Read Commands](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#creating-datasets-using-read-commands) (highlighting mine):

> The most programmatic way to create a Dataset is to invoke a `read` command on the `SparkSession`. This will build a `DataFrameReader`. Specify `format` as **org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra**. You can then use `options` to give a map of `Map[String,String]` of options as described above. Then finish by calling `load` to actually get a Dataset. This code is all lazy and will not actually load any data until an action is called.

---

There is [org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLRow](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/2.0.2/spark-cassandra-connector/#org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLRow) object that seems to offer a conversion from `com.datastax.driver.core.Row` to `org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLRow`:

```
fromJavaDriverRow(row: com.datastax.driver.core.Row, metaData: CassandraRowMetadata): CassandraSQLRow
```

My limited experience with the Spark Cassandra Connector suggests to use implicit conversions if needed.

```
// bring all the implicit goodies from the Spark Cassandra Connector
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the links were very helpful. I converted the code to spark.read.format and it is working now. I see `saveToCassandra` everywhere but for appending a large number of rows in a dataframe, which  API should I use? The Cassandra persistence is within`.forEachRDD` and hence needs to be performance-oriented

Comment: That begs another question then.